# Get values in an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I have an array of JSON objects like so:

```
[
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }
]
```

I want to loop through them and echo them out in a list. How can I do it?

Comment: just to add, theres nothing special about json. its just a javascript object initialization graph.. in your example you have an array (the square brackets), with objects in it (the curly bracket syntax).. you should check out object and array literals in javascript to reveal the 'magic'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
 var a = [
     { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
     { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
     { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
     { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
     { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }
 ];

 function iter() {
     for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
         var json = a[i];
         for(var prop in json) {
              alert(json[prop]);
                          // or myArray.push(json[prop]) or whatever you want
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = [
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" },
    { name: "tom", text: "tasty" }
]

for(var i in json){
    var json2 = json[i];
    for(var j in json2){
        console.log(i+'-'+j+" : "+json2[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
var jsonArray = [
  { name: "Alice", text: "a" },
  { name: "Bob",   text: "b" },
  { name: "Carol", text: "c" },
  { name: "Dave",  text: "d" }
];

jsonArray.forEach(function(json){
  for(var key in json){
    var log = "Key: {0} - Value: {1}";
    log = log.replace("{0}", key); // key
    log = log.replace("{1}", json[key]); // value
    console.log(log);
  }
});
```

If you want to target newer browsers, you can use `Objects.keys`:

```
var jsonArray = [
  { name: "Alice", text: "a" },
  { name: "Bob",   text: "b" },
  { name: "Carol", text: "c" },
  { name: "Dave",  text: "d" }
];

jsonArray.forEach(function(json){
  Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key){
    var log = "Key: {0} - Value: {1}";
    log = log.replace("{0}", key); // key
    log = log.replace("{1}", json[key]); // value
    console.log(log);
  });
});
```